# Strikethrough font in DynamicJasper report

Tags: java, dynamic-jasper

How to set attribute strikethrough to Font in DynamicJasper. There are simple ways to make font italic or underlined but no way to change strikethrough.

Answer (score 0):

Have found the solution - quite easy to use ex in ConditionalStyle:

```
public class StrikeThroughJasperStyle extends Style {

@Override
protected void setJRBaseStyleProperties(JRBaseStyle transformedStyle) {
    transformedStyle.setStrikeThrough(true);
}
```

}